# Why Refreshing access token gets unauthorized?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

As access token expires, client sends GET request with /refresh endpoint,but it ended with 401-unauthorized.

I have configured this request in webConfig. so, it does not need authorization. I have passed access token in header of /refresh request.

Note: If I don't pass token in header of /refresh request, It worked fine.

JwtAuthenticationController.java:

```
@RestController
public class JwtAuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/refresh", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> refreshAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

        final String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        final String username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        final UserDetails user =  userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if ((user.getUsername()).equals(username) && jwtUtils.isTokenExpired(token)) {
            final String refreshedToken = jwtUtils.refreshToken(token);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(refreshedToken));
        } 
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()             
                .exceptionHandling()
               .antMatchers("/register","/refresh")
               .permitAll()                   
               .anyRequest().authenticated();                     

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);

        if (authToken != null && authToken.startsWith(BEARER_PREFIX)) {
            try {
                authToken = authToken.substring(BEARER_PREFIX_LENGTH);
                username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }
        else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
   }
}
```

JwtUtils.java

```
private Claims getClaimsFromToken(String token) {
     return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .requireIssuer(issuer)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
}
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsGU5.jpg)

I am unable to find out why this happen? What is the solution to get new access token using client sent refresh token.

Comment: Hi. In what line of your 3 java files the error is throwed? Do you have logs?

Comment: Question updated. I have got error at line in jwtUtils file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I don't pass token in header of /refresh request, It worked fine.

This is probably because of the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`. I think you should exclude also the `/refresh` from the check, so:

```
   if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("/refresh") {
    if (authToken != null && authToken.startsWith(BEARER_PREFIX)) {
    //same logic
    }
   }
```

Comment: hey, can you tell me, I have defined /refresh in antmatchers in web config, Then why I have to do this?